# Busy Coder - Sample Project Download

Tags: android, commonsware

How do I download the sample projects in one hit? eg. the Basic/Label project link gives me a page of separate files to download. Can't I download the entire thing in a .zip like the BlankProject.zip on the releases page? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On all GitHub repositories, like [the cw-omnibus one](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus) for [The Busy Coder's Guide to Android Development](http://commonsware.com/Android), there is a "Download ZIP" button that you can use to download a ZIP file of the selected tag or branch of the repository. So, for example, if you switch to the `v5.8` tag, the "Download ZIP" button will let you download [a ZIP file containing the Version 5.8 edition of the samples](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/archive/v5.8.zip).